# java.lang.UnknownError is thrown out by JVM

Tags: java, ajax, spring, websphere, jackson

We have a web application using Spring 3.1.2. jackson 1.9.6 is used to convert json message by Spring. The application is deployed into IBM Websphere 6.1 on iSeries system.

Right now we are experiencing a java.lang.UnknownError coming from jackson jar. And it is causing all ajax request failed. But normal http get/post has no issues.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnknownError
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.hasSerializerFor(StdSerializerProvider.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.canSerialize(ObjectMapper.java:1785)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.canWrite(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.support.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.getProducibleMediaTypes(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:224)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.support.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.support.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:144)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.support.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:101)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:62)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:491)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:445)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    ... 33 more
```

Any ideas on what is the root cause to it? j`ava.lang.UnknownError` is thrown when an unknown but serious exception has occurred in the Java Virtual Machine. Does anybody know how to get JVM log on `java.lang.UnknownError`? Or how to troubleshoot this kind of error?

Comment: If you can, I'd recommend getting a copy of the source for the jackson .jar file and seeing if the code throws UnknownError.  If not, and it's really a VM exception, you'll need to report it to IBM.

Comment: Yes, if it is a definite VM exception, we would like to report it to IBM. But before that, we want to exclude the possible causes inside our application.

Answer (score 0):

The [Jackson 1.9.6 code](http://svn.codehaus.org/jackson/tags/1.9/1.9.6/src/mapper/java/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ser/StdSerializerProvider.java) does not throw this error itself - it's something (as the javadoc you found implies) within the jvm itself.

Do you see anything in `SystemError.log` when this happens?

If not, I'd submit a PMR to IBM for guidance. If this is not an option, the next thing I would try is to enable debug mode in the jvm and attach from RAD, eclipse, or your favorite IDE. Set an exception breakpoint on `java.lang.UnknownError` and see where it may be coming from.  I would download the Jackson source and have it during the debug session to step into the source in the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The error stack above is what I get from stdout log. There is nothing in stderr log. The most frustrated thing is that we don't know how to replicate this error. We are getting this error by chance. I am wondering if any java profiling tool can help us to get deep jvm logs.